# Determining per-machine vs. per-user via command line on Windows

Tags: windows

How can I determine in Windows whether a program is installed per-machine or per-user from the command line? I am mainly concerned about Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to detect this. The only difference between "per-machine" and "per-user" is if the program saves its settings in a place that is unique per user (`HKEY_LOCAL_USER` in the registry and the `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder in the filesystem) or shared among all users (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the registry and `%PROGRAMDATA%` in the filesystem)

All that is internal and custom to every program ever written and there is no generic "flag" you could read somewhere that could tell you which method a program is using.

If you want to know if a specific program is installed as per-user or per-machine, open a new question and be sure to include the details of which program you want to know about.

Comment: Also %LOCALAPPDATA% for user-specific non-roaming data (%APPDATA% is for roaming data).

Comment: I'm most interested in Python. This amount of pointer should be handy enough, thanks.

Comment: If a program is installed in `Program Files`, most likely it was installed in *per-machine* mode. If it's installed in another directory, you can never be sure. However, if a program is installed into user's profile, most likely it was installed in *per-user* mode.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Not necessarily. A program can be installed in Program files but a global setting can alternate if it stores its user settings in `%appdata%` or `%programdata%` (Notepad++ does this)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The question was about per-machine or per-user *installation* of a program. Notepad++ installs in per-machine mode. It perfectly matches the pattern I described. At the same time, almost all applications have *per-user settings* even if *installed per-machine* in `Program Files` but it's another question, isn't it?